# mousemove в Chrome работает рывками

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Во всех браузерах работает нормально а Chrome дергается.

http://codepen.io/Ifgen/pen/obqQPd

```
$('.wraper').mousemove(function( event ) {    
    var containerWidth = $(this).innerWidth(),
        containerHeight = $(this).innerHeight(),
        mousePositionX = (event.pageX / containerWidth) * 100,
        mousePositionY = (event.pageY /containerHeight) * 100;

        $(this).css('background-position', mousePositionX + '%' + ' ' + mousePositionY + '%');
});
```

И заодно может кто подскажет как это событие заставить работать на touch устройствах?

Comment: _как это событие заставить работать на touch устройствах?_ - никак, там используются свои события

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про тач вам ответили, про производительность в хроме - чуть поправил код, чтобы подставлялись целые числа в background-position, на глаз есть небольшой прирост.

```
$('.wraper').mousemove(function( event ) {

var container = $(this),
    containerWidth = container.innerWidth(),
    containerHeight = container.innerHeight(),
    mousePositionX = (event.pageX / containerWidth) * 100,
    mousePositionY = (event.pageY /containerHeight) * 100;

container.css('background-position', ~~mousePositionX + '%' + ' ' + ~~mousePositionY + '%');

});
```

Comment: Не разбирались с перерисовкой? Помнится, в CSS можно добиться значительной оптимизации для простых перемещений блока, при которых он не перерисовывается.

Comment: [Наскоро набросал пример](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXGxGb) – если двигать блок с помощью `transform: translate(x,y)` – браузер быстрее перерисовывает. В примере картинка цепляется за мышь левым верхним углом – это не готовое решение для вопрошающего – пускай сам доделает.

Comment: Хе хе, я тоже набросал =)
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoewmX

Comment: Зачётно! : ) Ещё б [инерционность](https://apps.sergeisokolov.com/calligraphy/) добавить для небольшой плавности )

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы работало быстрее, можно использовать более «дешёвую» для перформанса анимацию через свойства CSS3 [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). Такие анимации как перемещение, поворот, увеличение могут выполняться браузером супер-эффективно и быстро.

Набросал [пример](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXGxGb), чтобы оценить скорость перерисовки – картинка просто следует за мышью своим левым верхним углом. Сравните, насколько это более плавно/быстро?

С точки зрения motion design было бы здорово добавить движению фона небольшую инерционность. Будто картинка не жестко привязана к мыши, а на эластичной резинке, но без колебаний.

Это можно сделать просто через CSS, добавив `transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;` к анимируемому блоку. Но это криво работает с постоянным движением мыши – картинка с каждым скачком мыши будет в «плавном» начале очередного смягчённого движения - будет будто тормозить.

А лучше это можно сделать «кривой преследования» – представьте собаку, которая бежит по полю всегда прямо на зайца, где он находится в очередной момент. Координаты картинки в каждый момент времени получают инкремент как долю от вектора из картинки на мышку. Вот [пример](https://apps.sergeisokolov.com/calligraphy/) - тут я делал аж четыре цели, последовательно гоняющихся друг за другом и за мышкой. Для картинки достаточно мышки и первой за ней целью.